# Does this series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}}$

Is there an elementary way to show that this *diverges*?

Comment: Certainly not, since it does not converge (you also should not let it start at 0 but that's tanegential. ). To see this try to  compare it to the harmonic series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+n}}>\frac1{n+1}$$

Comment: For those who are confused, square both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\sim \frac 1n.$$

So by comparaison to Riemann example, this series diverges.